# Show Articles in Sidebar

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Similar to my last question. I have followed this guide to my first rails app. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.htmlccap

I made a layout in my layout view and I would like to make a side bar the lists all the articles. I made a partial that included the loop of article titles and a link.

For some reason it only seems to work on the articles page... so http://localhost:3000/articles

I assume that is because I haven't created the def for that in my controller? I am not sure how to go about creating it though for a partial.

My understanding is that I could go something like

```
def index
  @articles = article.all
end
```

But since it is a partial with _sidebar.html.erb I'm not sure how to do it.

Any help as always is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems like you don't know which `controller` or `action` you are using. You can add `<%= params %>` in your partial view  to display what `controller` and `action` you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're rendering the sidebar partial from your layout. The best way to accomplish this is to create a `before_action` filter in your `ApplicationController`

You should end up with something like this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :excption
  before_action :fetch_articles

protected
  def fetch_articles
    @articles = Article.limit(10) # Gets 10 articles
  end
end
```

This will run the `fetch_articles` method before every action in your rails app.
Which means the `@articles` variable will be available for the sidebar partial whenever a new action is rendered.

Comment: I can't seem to make it work... I just placed my code for the sidebar above. I must be missing something simple. I'm adding the sidebar using `<%= render '/shared/sidebar' %>`

Comment: I'm a dummy. I never pluralized the @articles :( Thanks for your help @chrisgooley!

Answer (score 0):

You should place your code in the

```
module ApplicationHelper
  include Radio::AttributeBuilder

   def fetch_articles
    @articles = Article.limit(10) # Gets 10 articles
  end
end
```

and call this method for the show in your helper